# Is there a way to measure the margins of a pdf file using image processing in python?

Tags: python, pdf, image-processing, nlp, html-content-extraction

Up to now, I have used different types of packages in Python to extract information from PDF files, but I couldn't find a way to measure the margins of the PDF document. As an example, I wanted to get the size of the margins on the four sides of the pdf page.

I have used pdfcrop package to remove the white spaces(margins) but couldn't measure the margin size.

Comment: Page margins are not part of the PDF file. The PDF creator has decided where his text should land, and that's all about it. But for each page you can simply determine the union rectangle of all text boundary boxes. Then take the 4 rectangle stripes on each side of the union rectangle as margins present on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using PyMuPDF

```py
import fitz  # package PyMuPDF
doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")

for page in doc:
    rect = fitz.EMPTY_RECT()  # prepare an empty rectangle
    blocks = page.get_text("blocks")  # extract text and image blocks
    for b in blocks:
        rect |= b[:4]  # join rect with the block bbox
    print(f"Page {page.number} margins:")
    print(f"    Top {rect.y0}")
    print(f"   Left {rect.x0}")
    print(f"  Right {page.rect.width - rect.x1}")
    print(f" Bottom {page.rect.height - rect.y1}")
```

If someone is interested to extend the above to all possible page content - nd not just text or image, use the even faster method `page.get_bboxlog()`. This won't read or extract anything, instead only returns covered rectangles.
The above loop would then be:

```py
...
for page in doc:
    rect = fitz.EMPTY_RECT()  # prepare an empty rectangle
    for item in page.get_bboxlog():
        b = item[1]  # the bbox of the covered area
        rect |= b[:4]  # join rect with the block bbox

    print(f"Page {page.number} margins:")
    print(f"    Top {rect.y0}")
    print(f"   Left {rect.x0}")
    print(f"  Right {page.rect.width - rect.x1}")
    print(f" Bottom {page.rect.height - rect.y1}")
```